# What do these i915 errors mean in the Kernel log?

Tags: kernel, i915

Currently my kernel log has these errors,

```
i915: [drm] *ERROR* CPU pipe C FIFO underrun: transcoder,
i915: [drm] *ERROR* [ENCODER:350:DDI TC3/PHY TC3][DPRX] Failed to enable link training
i915: [drm] *ERROR* Step 2 of creating MST payload for 0000000095f4377a failed: -5
i915: [drm] *ERROR* CPU pipe C FIFO underrun: transcoder,
i915: [drm] *ERROR* [ENCODER:350:DDI TC3/PHY TC3][DPRX] Failed to enable link training
i915: [drm] *ERROR* Step 2 of creating MST payload for 0000000095f4377a failed: -5
i915: [drm] *ERROR* CPU pipe C FIFO underrun: transcoder,
```

What do they mean? Should they be concerning?

Comment: Please ask here by opening a bug report: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/intel/-/issues